# Getting error while calling delegatecall from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I was trying to call the setValue function in the FirstContract from the SecondContract, the EOA calling the function of SecondContract is owner of FirstContract and also passed the address of the first contract while deploying the SecondContract, still it is showing an error. I wanted to see I can modify the state variable of FirstContract from the SecondContract using delegatecall. If it is not possible to modify the state variable of FirstContract using delegatecall, please suggest any other alternative.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

contract FirstContract {
    address public owner;
    uint256 public value;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        value = 42;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function.");
        _;
    }

    function setValue(uint256 newValue) public onlyOwner {
        value = newValue;
    }
}

contract SecondContract {
    address public firstContractAddress;

    constructor(address _firstContractAddress) {
        firstContractAddress = _firstContractAddress;
    }

    function setValueInFirstContract(uint256 newValue) public {
        // Use delegatecall to call the setValue function in FirstContract
        (bool success, ) = firstContractAddress.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("setValue(uint256)", newValue)
        );

        require(success, "Delegatecall to FirstContract failed");
    }
}
```

```
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: SecondContract.setValueInFirstContract(uint256) 0xa13...eAD95value: 0 weidata: 0xe81...00015logs: 0hash: 0x5b6...ea523
status  false Transaction mined but execution failed
transaction hash    0x5b6b7d639223b1b875535885e6b4c3cdeb341b8302ef35b0575f1b55521ea523
block hash  0xe298d42613295a13762b310f85c04fb4992402ba11908d0011420b7faae325c2
block number    5
from    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to  SecondContract.setValueInFirstContract(uint256) 0xa131AD247055FD2e2aA8b156A11bdEc81b9eAD95
gas 3000000 gas
transaction cost    28470 gas 
execution cost  7266 gas 
input   0xe81...00015
decoded input   {
    "uint256 newValue": "21"
}
decoded output  {}
logs    []
val 0 wei
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With delegatecall, you read/modify the state of `SecondContract` and not `FirstContract`.

When the transaction reaches the modifier `onlyOwner` before setting the value, it will read `owner` not from `FirstContract` but from `SecondContract`. You may think that `SecondContract` doesn't have a `owner` variable, but that doesn't matter: it will read its first state variable because that's where `FirstContract` saved it.

You can try writing `SecondContract` like this, and the transaction should succeed.

```
contract SecondContract {
    address public owner;  // add this
    address public firstContractAddress;

    constructor(address _firstContractAddress) {
        owner = msg.sender;  // add this
        firstContractAddress = _firstContractAddress;
    }

    function setValueInFirstContract(uint256 newValue) public {
        // Use delegatecall to call the setValue function in FirstContract
        (bool success, ) = firstContractAddress.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("setValue(uint256)", newValue)
        );

        require(success, "Delegatecall to FirstContract failed");
    }
}
```

After this transaction, try looking at `firstContractAddress`. It changed! That's because `value` was written in the second slot, so it wrote over `firstContractAddress`. It's a very bad bug, that's why you should only use `delegatecall` to a contract that shares the same state layout.

---

> If it is not possible to modify the state variable of FirstContract using delegatecall, please suggest any other alternative.

Just call FirstContract directly. It's the simplest (and only) way.